# PHP GET ONly gets data before Underscore or Hyphen

Tags: php

i am trying to retrieve the ID of a URL which contains underscore or hyphen using PHP $_GET.
It only fetches the data before the underscore but not everything. I need to fetch everything in the data.

For example https://example.com/view-all-collections/Fragrances-room  will only fetch **Fragrances** instead of **fragrances-room**.
this is the old url eaxmple.com/view-all-collections.php?d=fragrances-room . I used htaccess to clean the url

```
$_GET['id'];
```

This is my Htaccess  `RewriteRule ^view-all-collections/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) view-all-collection.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

Please how can i solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Please show your code so we can see how you're attempting it.

Comment: i am using something like this $_GET['id']

Comment: `$_GET` should work fine for this. ***.htaccess*** is the issue.